# Is there a way to open HTTP web in Edge using selenium and iedriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

So i'm using this code but if the web is HTTP it opens on IE instead of Edge.

```
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.EdgeExecutablePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe";
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);

        driver.Url = "some http web";
```

is there a way to force it on edge?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download Microsoft Edge Driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) and use that. The name of the class your code currently uses should give you a hint about why Internet Explorer is being opened:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is right in the name: **InternetExplorer**Driver. You are using the web driver for Internet Explorer. If you want to automate Edge, you need to use EdgeDriver.

I think the curious thing is that Edge is launched when loading an HTTPS URL when using InternetExplorerDriver. I suspect there are Windows Policies installed that override Internet Explorer causing Edge to be launched instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create `InternetExplorerDriver` and pass the `InternetExplorerOptions`:

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
{
    AttachToEdgeChrome = true,
    EdgeExecutablePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
};

var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.Url = "https://example.com";
```

This will open Edge in IE mode...
If you don't need IE mode you need to use `EdgeDriver` instead of `InternetExplorerDriver` and `EdgeOption` instead of `InternetExplorerOptions`